# Database transactions causing query problems with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I'm using CodeIgniter and tansactions but there is something I can't figure out.

I've managed to narrow down the issue to the transactions themselves so I will post the different results I get.

**Scenario 1:**

> Mycontroller.php

```
$call_1 = a_check($data1); // a_check is located in a Helper
$call_2 = a_check($data2);
```

> mycustomhelper.php

```
function a_check($data){
  $ci->db->trans_start();
       // If some conditions, run Query 1 below
       $ci->db->set('progress', $progress);
       $ci->db->where('id_player' , $UserID);                          
       $ci->db->update('user_a');

       // If some other conditions, run Query 2 below
       $sql = "UPDATE achievements SET count = count+1 WHERE id_a = $a_id;
       $ci->db->query($sql);
  $ci->db->trans_complete();
}
```

> Results: Query 1 during the second call (`$call_2`) will ONLY be executed if Query 1 during `$call_1` is executed.

**Scenario 2:** (removed the transactions)

> Mycontroller.php

```
$call_1 = a_check($data1); // a_check is located in a Helper
$call_2 = a_check($data2);
```

> mycustomhelper.php

```
function a_check($data){
       // If some conditions, run Query 1 below
       $ci->db->set('progress', $progress);
       $ci->db->where('id_player' , $UserID);                          
       $ci->db->update('user_a');

       // If some other conditions, run Query 2 below
       $sql = "UPDATE achievements SET count = count+1 WHERE id_a = $a_id;
       $ci->db->query($sql);
}
```

> Results: Query 1 will be executed during `$call_1` and `$call_2` (as expected).

**Scenario 3:** (not running $call_1)

> Mycontroller.php

```
// $call_1 = a_check($data1); // a_check is located in a Helper
$call_2 = a_check($data2);
```

> mycustomhelper.php

```
function a_check($data){
   $ci->db->trans_start();
       // If some conditions, run Query 1 below
       $ci->db->set('progress', $progress);
       $ci->db->where('id_player' , $UserID);                          
       $ci->db->update('user_a');

       // If some other conditions, run Query 2 below
       $sql = "UPDATE achievements SET count = count+1 WHERE id_a = $a_id;
       $ci->db->query($sql);
    $ci->db->trans_complete();
}
```

> Results: Query 1 will be executed during `$call_2`.

I'm using the transactions for error handling (removed from this code sample) but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: File naming CI https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: That was just a typo when simplifying the code. I changed the names to respect the naming convention but the problem persists.